# python: changing from print to return does not process items right

Tags: python, set, return

I created a program that reads a couchDB to list followers and friends ids of a single twitter user. Friends are identified under the group “friend_edges” and followers under “follower_edges”.

I use the intersection operation between sets -set1.intersection(set.2)- in order to obtain the list of those who are both friends and followers.

When I use `print` to see the outputs, the results are correct. But when I change to `return` to process the results, it only processes friends, not followers.

Can somebody give me a clue of what I'm doing wrong and how to improve the code?.... thanks in advance.

```
from twitter_login import oauth_login
from twitter_DB import load_from_DB
from sets import Set


def friends_and_followers(doc):
    if 'friend_edges' in doc.keys(): 
        flist = []        
        for x in doc['friend_edges']:
            flist.append(x)
        #print "Number of friends: ", len(flist) <-- shows the right number of items
        return flist
    else:
        return []

    if 'follower_edges' in doc.keys():
        followlist = []        
        for x in doc['follower_edges']:
            followlist.append(x)
        #print "Number of followers: ", len(followlist) <-- shows the right number of items
        return followlist
    else:
        return []

    flist = Set(flist)
    followlist = Set(followlist)
    return flist.intersection(followlist)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_api = oauth_login()
    DBname = 'users-aguy-+-only'
    ff_results = load_from_DB(DBname)
    print 'number loaded', len(ff_results)

    for doc in ff_results:
        together = friends_and_followers(doc)
        print "Friends and followers of a guy: ", together
```

Answer (score 3):

A return statement stops execution of that method and returns to the calling method, so by adding a return statement you are saying, "Stop here and go back to where you came from"

You need to store both the values you want returned in variables and return them at the same time at the end of your method:

```
return value1, value2
```

You will call this with something like this:

```
val1, val2 = get_value1_and_value2(input)
```

It might make more sense to just break that up into two separate methods that each return the correct value though.